# PathTooLongException in C# code

Tags: c#, pathtoolongexception

i have the following code:

```
 public static void Serialize()
    {

        List<string> dirs = FileHelper.GetFilesRecursive(fileDirectoryPath);
        List<string> dirFiles = new List<string>();
        foreach (string p in dirs)
        {
            string path = p;

            string lastAccessTime = File.GetLastAccessTime(path).ToString();


            bool DirFile = File.Exists(path);
            FileInfo fInf = new FileInfo(path);
            long lengthInk = fInf.Length / 1024;

            DateTime lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(p);
            dirFiles.Add(p + "|" + lastAccessTime.ToString() + "|" + DirFile.ToString() + "|" + lastWriteTime.ToString() + "|" + lengthInk.ToString() + " kb");


        }
```

I keep hitting a PathTooLongException error with the following line:

```
string lastAccessTime = File.GetLastAccessTime(path).ToString();
```

The application drills into a drive and finds all files/folders w/in the drive.  I cannot change this path but since it is above 260 characters...how to work around this?

Comment: use windows api [http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2011/02/13/getting-around-pathtoolongexception-on-file-move-with-windows-native-api.aspx](http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2011/02/13/getting-around-pathtoolongexception-on-file-move-with-windows-native-api.aspx)

Comment: My own and other answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29605805/589059) suggest some wrapper libraries you can use for dealing with long paths.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid System.IO.PathTooLongException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530109/how-to-avoid-system-io-pathtoolongexception)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetLastAccessTime()` call, with a full path can [exceed the internal limit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pathtoolongexception.aspx) (which is OS-version specific, but typically 260 characters) on the maximum length for a fully qualified file path.

One way to avoid this, is to use [`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx) to change the current system directory and then call `GetLastAccessTime()` with only a relative path. Just make sure you change your current directory back to what you started from to avoid unexpected issues.

Comment: I reached this response researching for a similar issue. But I find that SetCurrentDirectory also throws PathTooLongExceptipn. My question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050199/directory-setcurrentdirectory-throws-pathtoolongexception. Appreciate any comments you have.

Comment: @Hemal: `SetCurrentDirectory()` accepts relative paths. Have you tried splitting the operation into two calls? So, for example to navigate to `C:\FirstPart\SecondPart\ThirdPart` you would do: `SetCurrentDirectory("C:\\FirstPart\\SecondPart"); SetCurrentDirectory(".\\ThirdPart");`. By splitting the directory navigation into multiple steps you may be able to sidestep the path length limitations.

Comment: thanks for responding. Yes, I tried relative paths but that also gives the same exception when I reach the length limit.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the `.LastAccessTime` property of Delimon.Win32.IO.FileInfo, might do the trick.

Delimon is a library on Microsoft TechNet for overcoming the long filenames problem, it's called **[Delimon.Win32.I​O Library (V4.0)](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DelimonWin32IO-Library-V40-7ff6b16c)** and it has its own versions of key classes from System.IO

For example, you would replace:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles
```

with

```
Delimon.Win32.IO.Directory.GetFiles
```

which will let you handle long files and folders.

From the website:

> Delimon.Win32.IO replaces basic file functions of System.IO and
>   supports File & Folder names up to up to 32,767 Characters.
>
> This Library is written on .NET Framework 4.0 and can be used either
>   on x86 & x64 systems. The File & Folder limitations of the standard
>   System.IO namespace can work with files that have 260 characters in a
>   filename and 240 characters in a folder name (MAX_PATH is usually
>   configured as 260 characters). Typically you run into the
>   System.IO.PathTooLongException Error with the Standard .NET Library.

Comment: Followed this advice yesterday but GetFileSystemInfos() threw not implemented exception. Also read that it's no longer maintained, and saw this suggested instead: https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS

Answer (score 0):

.NET doesn't support Unicode file paths, so the only option I know of in this case is using P/Invoke (unless, of course, you can change the path) to call Win32 API functions that do support them. You can look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maximum_path_length) for instructions on how to use Unicode file path to break the 260 characters barrier.

Answer (score 0):

As Microsoft says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maximum_path_length), there is a Windows limitation on 260 characters.

You can try to avoid this with a [symbolic link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365680%28VS.85%29.aspx) (not sure...).

Comment: The link with the limitation actually contains the solution (see my answer to the question).