# 'Could not load file or assembly System.IO.Compression' on UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget, windows-10-universal, zip

My application is a Universal Window Platform application. I try to implement a Runtime Component to decompress a zipped folder. One of my requirements is that paths which are longer than 260 characters can be handled.

```
public static IAsyncActionWithProgress < string > Unzip(string zipPath, string destination) {
    return AsyncInfo.Run < string > (async(_, progress) => {
        var zipFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(zipPath));

        try {
            Stream stream = await zipFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream);
            archive.ExtractToDirectory(destination);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to execute my method getting following exception message:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Compression, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Zip.Zip.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Unzip>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Zip.Zip.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Unzip>b__0(CancellationToken _, IProgress`1 progress)
   at System.Thread (~4340)
```

I tried to add System.IO.Compression with NuGet but I still get the same error. The zip file and the destination folder exist.

I tried to debug my project on Visual Studio 2015 instead of Visual Studio 2017 and found out that I can use System.IO.Compression in that way but there is a restriction for the length of paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, by testing on my side, with the newest Visual Studio 2017, your code snippet could work well with file path less than 260 characters by default. If using a longer path than 260 characters visual studio 2017 will throw exception

> System.IO.PathTooLongException: 'The filename or extension is too long.

which is same as Visual Studio 2015. SO please check if you are using the namespace correctly. `using System.IO.Compression;`

> One of my requirements is that paths which are longer than 260 characters can be handled.

Secondly, the error is thrown when you tried to get the file by `GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` method. So this is not the `System.IO.Compression` namespace issue, what you actually need to resolve is Maximum Path Length Limitation, details please reference [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). For more details about file path too long issue please try to reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745215/best-way-to-resolve-file-path-too-long-exception). But they may not suit for UWP app.

In UWP app you can use a [`FileOpenPicker`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745215/best-way-to-resolve-file-path-too-long-exception) to get the file and pass the file to the component for reading the file stream. The file picker will convert the long file name to a shot one like "xxx-UN~1.ZIP" for reading.

```
FileOpenPicker openpicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".zip");
var zipfile = await openpicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
Stream stream = await zipfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream);
archive.ExtractToDirectory(destination);
```

I recommend you to avoid using long file path.