# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, coded-ui-tests, mtm

**Error**: Error adding test case [5696] to test run: Unable to load the test container '\Build9-9-9\Builds\9.9.9 Build TestSuite\9.9.9 Build TestSuite_20170713.1\sample1.dll' or one of its dependencies. Error details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Versions**- TFS 13 ,
Microsoft visual studio enterprise 17 ,
Test Agent 17 ,
Test Controller 17 ,
Microsoft test manager 17,
Not able to resolve this. Please help.

**Able to load the DLL but tests are not getting executed:** 
[MTM Test Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZK00.png)

**Error list includes the following:**

"ID"    "Date and time" "Message"
18  "07/24/2017 12:46:16"   "Timestamp '7/24/2017 4:30:29 PM'; TestOutcome 'Warning'; Message 'Warning: Test Run deployment issue: Failed to access the file 'C:\Users\bmaster\AppData\Local\VSEQT\QTController\rm\1594\bmaster_SW-TESTCON 2017-07-24 12_29_29\Out\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\ProgressiveReveal\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.ProgressiveRevealProvider.dll': System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.'."

"ID"    "Date and time" "Message"
16  "07/24/2017 12:46:16"   "Timestamp '7/24/2017 4:30:28 PM'; TestOutcome 'Warning'; Message 'Warning: Test Run deployment issue: Failed to access the file 'C:\Users\bmaster\AppData\Local\VSEQT\QTController\rm\1594\bmaster_SW-TESTCON 2017-07-24 12_29_29\Out\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\AssemblyMetadata\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.AssemblyMetadataProvider.dll': System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.'."

"ID"    "Date and time" "Message"
18  "07/24/2017 12:46:16"   "Timestamp '7/24/2017 4:30:29 PM'; TestOutcome 'Warning'; Message 'Warning: Test Run deployment issue: Failed to access the file 'C:\Users\bmaster\AppData\Local\VSEQT\QTController\rm\1594\bmaster_SW-TESTCON 2017-07-24 12_29_29\Out\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\ProgressiveReveal\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.ProgressiveRevealProvider.dll': System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.'."

**And so on!!**

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/lab-management/install-configure-test-agents), TFS 2013 and Test Agent 2017 is not compatible.

> If you need your test agent or test controller to work with TFS 2013,
>   use Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 and configure the
>   test controller.

So, you need to install Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 for your test agent.

---

**UPDATE:**

For the new error:

> The test automation associated with the following test case **could
>   not be found: [5696]**. Run the test case again using a build that
>   contains the binary with the test automation.

Based on the error message and my test, it means the test method cannot be found in the specified DLL file that in the drop folder.

So, please check whether there is the test method (Has TestMethod attribute marked) in the specified test project.

After that, please query that build again and do the test with the newer build.

---

**UPDATE2:**

It's another issue : PathTooLongException

So, you need to shorten the path to resolve it.

For example: The .dll file is currently located at :

```
C:\Users\bmaster\AppData\Local\VSEQT\QTController\rm\1594\bmaster_SW-TESTCON 2017-07-24 12_29_29\Out\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\AssemblyMetadata\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.AssemblyMetadataProvider.dll'
```

You can think a way to Move it to something like:

```
C:\VS\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.AssemblyMetadataProvider.dll
```

To shorten the path, you can reference this thread: [Best way to resolve file path too long exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745215/best-way-to-resolve-file-path-too-long-exception)

Comment: @Srushti Have you resolved your issue? Any update for this?

Comment: Yep Thank you! Resolved the version error. Used  Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.

Comment: New error is popping now: The test automation associated with the following test case could not be found: [5696]. Run the test case again using a build that contains the binary with the test automation.

Comment: @Srushti Please check if you have associated automated tests with test case correctly, see https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/associate-automated-test-with-test-case

Comment: Yes I have associated the test with test case correctly

Comment: @Srushti Please see the updated answer for further troubleshooting.

Comment: I am able to load the DLL now but the tests are not getting executed. I have provided the screenshot of the test logs.

Comment: @Srushti So,just as I mentioned in the update answer, please check whether there is the test method (Has TestMethod attribute marked) in the specified test project. It will execute nothing If there is no test method.

Comment: @Srushti The message is clear that PathTooLongException, So, you need to shorten the Path length, see the updated answer.  BTW, I suggest you open a new thread for the new issue, thus we can track the questions more effective, and benefit for other communities to read this question.