# Unable to copy file specified file name is too long. When publishing bot to azure

Tags: c#, azure

I have this error. What i did is download a bot template from azure. Then copy my local bot to that bot template that i downloaded from azure. When i am publishing i am receiving this error.
It seems the file in the bin is having a loop. That's why the path is too long.
How to resolve this?

[image]
update pic[image]

Comment: Which bot template did you download? How did you copy your local bot to that template?

Comment: The basic template. I has a different structure so i copy my old bot to the template. i copied the startup of the old one.

Comment: Have you tried to put the project in the root directory(like d:\)? If you extract the downloaded project, you will get two-level directory. Just copy the send level directory(the project) to another place and try again.

Comment: That worked sir the error is gone thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I have added this to the answer. Please make it as answer. It will also be helpful to the others.

Comment: The filename includes the directory path to the file.  Reduce the number of directories prior to the project, or move the project to another location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to resolve file path too long exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745215/best-way-to-resolve-file-path-too-long-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to put the project in the root directory(like d:) If you extract the downloaded project, you will get two-level directory. Just copy the send level directory(the project) to another place and try again

Comment: I just copy the whole folder to a root directory? Cause the error is back.

Comment: @user10860402 You encountered the same error again?

Comment: Yes sir i attached the updated pic. looks like directory is looping in bin

Comment: Do you need the code in template bot? If not, you can try my answer in your another question, you just need the publishsettings from that template bot.

Comment: I dont need the code in the template. Do you mind opening a chat sir?

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191645/discussion-between-tony-ju-and-user10860402).

Comment: @user10860402 I can not send message in that chat window, anything wrong?

Comment: I dont know sir i can still chat in the chat window.

Comment: @user10860402 'There seems to be a problem connecting to the server. Please check your internet connection and reload this page' I am getting this message.

Comment: Weird i don't seem to have that problem sir.

Comment: I am here sir sorry