# ASP.Net Web Application - Windows 10 - IIS Express - System.IO.PathTooLongException

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis-express

I'm trying to get an ASP.Net Web Application to be able to write a long filename but keep getting a `System.IO.PathTooLongException`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pathtoolongexception?view=netframework-4.8

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\LongFileName" + new string('0', 500) + ".txt", "LongFileName");
```

I've tried setting group policy and registry settings to enable long file paths. This hasn't worked. I've tried adding an `app.manifest` file to my project with the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
        <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

This still isn't working. I'm wondering if the issue is that it being a web application I cannot have a manifest file and this needs to be a setting for IIS Express?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [best-way-to-resolve-file-path-too-long-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745215/best-way-to-resolve-file-path-too-long-exception)

Comment: I'm not sure, but in the APIs you need to prefix long file names exceeding MAX_PATH (256) with `\\?\`, have you tried this? See [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd)