# How to create files in folders with long names. (Avoid PathTooLongException)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid System.IO.PathTooLongException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530109/how-to-avoid-system-io-pathtoolongexception)

In my application folder structure has a very long time.
I need the files saved in this folder (I have no option to change the schema folder!)

**[Edited]**

```
using (var fileStream = File.Create(@"\\?\" + filePath, (int) file.Value.Length))
{
    var bytesInStream = new byte[file.Value.Length];
    file.Value.Read(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
    fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
}
```

The problem is that the full path "filePath" has more than 260 characters!

### Error:

> System.IO.PathTooLongException The specified path, file name, or both
>   are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
>   characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

But he must be saved in this folder!

**How, without changing the folder structure or file name, I can save this file in this folder?**

Comment: Can you refer to the files by their DOS shortened names? AKA `Documents and Settings` can typically be be shorted to `DOCUMEN~1` or something.

Comment: I modified the code to:
`using (var fileStream = File.Create(@"\\?\" + filePath, (int) file.Value.Length))`  
But the same error occurs!

Comment: Why do you need such long filenames?

Comment: I do not need file name logos. The problem is that the full path is long! "\\?\C:\Users\Riderman_2\Work\datafilme\src\DataFilme\DataFilme\App_Files\Produtos\118dc343-0025-4016-c92a-48d02165d699\Visoes\861c9831-f8ce-7946-9e9e-702cdc9d99ca\Valores\32ed0254-77be-0d59-a995-65be34749991\ISIS para configuração de digitalizadores da série i920.pdf"  > Folder Product > {'Product ID'}> Folder View> {'id view'}> Folder View Item> {'ID view item'}> Archives

Answer (score 2):

Great article about using long paths and the headaches involved.  Ensure you ACTUALLY need them before heading down this path.  Relative paths don't working "...\a.txt"

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx

Other alternatives are to use the Win32 API to make your calls directly.

Comment: I've read this article! And several other related =)!   I can not change the folder structure or even the file name! I really need to create files in a folder structure long!