# C# I/O library that supports long paths (to solve PathTooLongException)

Tags: c#, winapi, io, pathtoolongexception

My open source [software](http://cmissync.com) synchronizes a remote folder to the local desktop. The remote folder can be on Alfresco, where path length has no limit (`/root/very/very/very/long/name.txt`).

When developing the application I used `System.IO.File.OpenWrite` and `System.IO.Stream.Write`, but it appears that [they don't support paths over a few hundred characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath), so users report errors like `PathTooLongException` when working with long paths.

[UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) paths must absolutely be avoided, because they lead to incompatibility with some applications.

What library/code should be used in this case?

It must be open source C#.

Comment: I just noticed you did the "post your own answer" feature. I am willing to bet you where pounding your head for a while figuring this out and now you want to share on how you solved it so others do not have to suffer. [I have been there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11346554/80274).

Answer (score 3):

[AlphaFS](http://alphafs.codeplex.com) lets you use very long paths (using the "\?\" style) and mimics the System.IO namespace.

You will probably be able to use this library just as if you were using System.IO. For example, AlphaFS.Win32.Filesystem.File.Copy() instead System.IO.File.Copy().

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12747217/226958))

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [Base Class Libraries Long Path implementation](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Long%20Path&referringTitle=Home). But be aware that not everything will work if you start to mix up with default .NET I/O methods.

Comment: This is the recommended solution. +1 Have used extensively before. I recall a bug in there at the time of the original release, but it's open source and I'm sure it's been since officially fixed.

Comment: +1 Great! The license is Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL) which is open source, even though it is unfortunately not compatible with the GNU-GPL: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#ms-pl

Answer (score 1):

"[.NET 2.0 Workaround for PathTooLongException](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22013/NET-2-0-Workaround-for-PathTooLongException)" (article+code).

Licensed under The Code Project Open License (CPOL), which is not open source [apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Project_Open_License).

Only 2 commits do not make for a very active project, though...

Comment: Ummm, its not really a "project" its just telling you to use a PInvoke to call `CreateFileW` and use `\\?\.` at the start of your path name.

Comment: I take it back, I looked at the source, he does put some work in to it. I would not be concerned about the "not too active" part. You are just wrapping the Windows API with a few helper functions, once you got rid of your bugs, there is not much more to do

Answer (score 1):

[Native File System Access](http://source.pelicandd.com/Codebase/Virtual%20file%20system/Source/Native%20File%20System%20Access/)

Since the revision 185 (February 19<sup>th</sup>, 2013), the library is covered by [Microsoft Public License (MS-PL)](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MS-PL), as specified in the headers of the source code files.

Looks promising, but author [advises](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/186456/1480) against using it in an enterprise environment, since the code is not solid enough.

This library has some [unit tests](http://source.pelicandd.com/Codebase/Virtual%20file%20system/Unit%20tests/Native%20File%20System%20Access%20Tests/), but lacks documentation.

Comment: I can't recommend this library. Basic functionality, like `File.Open` doesn't work (disposes the handle of the stream it returns and ignores the `access`/`share` parameters) and file enumeration silently ignores errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could try splitting the path up by using relative paths as outlined in this answer using:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()
```

[PathTooLongException in C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087565/pathtoolongexception-in-c-sharp-code)

Comment: Interesting... maybe there is a library that does this trick automatically for me?