# path,file name, or both are too long. name must be less than 260 characters,directory name must be less than 248 characters

Tags: asp.net, ssis, c#-3.0

Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.IO.PathTooLongException: **The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.**

I'm using this code in ;

```
public void Main()
{
    System.Net.WebClient myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
    myWebClient.DownloadFile(Dts.Variables[0].Value.ToString(),
                             Dts.Variable[1].Value.ToString());
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

where:

`Dts.Variables[0].Value.ToString() == https://secure.f-prot.com/keyportal/cgi-bin/keyportalorder.pl?u=l&p=ooetcetcd&product_id=1&number_of_u=3&type=1&length=a&partner_id=2932&order_ref=4&account_reference_name=audney&account_reference_value=margaretculclagers%sbcglobal.net`

`Dts.Variables[1].Value.ToString() == C:\Audiney_API_File\keyportal_accountinfo.pl.xml`

Kindly help me .

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530109/how-to-avoid-system-io-pathtoolongexception

Comment: Are you sure about the code that you have posted? I have tried the code with given values and got the xml file successfully.

Answer (score 1):

My Error is Resolved ..

Root cause's : I have used  wrong variable ..

i.e; Instead of writing like this (URL,LocalFolder )

I have written (LocalFolder,URL). :)..