# System.drawing.Image PathTooLong

Tags: c#, .net

I need to handle Images with really long paths (no way to save to shorter paths because files already exist in company). For the `System.IO.path` I had the same problem and found [AlphaFS](http://alphafs.alphaleonis.com/) (can handle long paths way over 260 chars), which works perfectly. Is there any way to do the same thing for the `System.drawing.Image` class?
Id need that in general, but as an example I get the `PathTooLong-Exception` when calling `Image.FromFile(path);`

Comment: This isn't really a question about `System.Drawing.Image` so much as dealing with long paths in .NET. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530109/how-to-avoid-system-io-pathtoolongexception

Comment: well as I wrote, for the Path class I found a solution. I really need one for the `System.drawing.Image`

Comment: If you can get a `Stream` or `byte[]` from AlphaFS using your long path then you can simply use Patrick's example to load the image using `FromStream`.

Comment: Also if you have a solution to the linked question, I would encourage you to post an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. You could load the file yourself, and then read the image from a stream:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(yourOwnReadBytes))
{
    Image i = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```