# C# - FileStream / Stream - PathTooLongException - Zeta Long Paths

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a windows forms application which will parse the compressed files. I am getting an exception

> System.IO.PathTooLongException upon debugging the files that were
>   being parsed and extracted have their fully qualified name over 259
>   characters. One of the posts here mentioned about Zeta Long Paths.

I have downloaded it via Nuget package and using it in my project.

ZlpIOHelper can be used to perform file handling function.

I went through the reference via object explorer and couldn't determine how to create a FileSteam using Zeta Long Paths.

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(archiveFilenameIn);

Stream inStream = File.OpenRead(gzArchiveName);
Stream gzipStream = new GZipInputStream(inStream);
```

How can the above functions be implemented using Zeta Long Paths? Or any other packages?

Not a duplicate question. .NET Version is 4.0 and long path package specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid System.IO.PathTooLongException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530109/how-to-avoid-system-io-pathtoolongexception)

Comment: @demo not a duplicate. The solution mentioned in that post is not applicable here as .NET Version is 4.0. Also, the question is how could the Stream be implemented using Zeta Long Paths.

Comment: If you compile on .NET 4.6.2, the path too long limit can be removed. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38889598/711061

Comment: @sam tried on .NET 4.6.2 and the mentioned method is Windows 10 dependent. Unfortunately, restricted to .NET 4.0.

Comment: @Tango not sure if still relevant for you, but see my proposed answer

Answer (score 2):

Creating a FileStream through **Zeta Long Path** is not automatic, but possible.

You must first get/create an **SafeFileHandle** to your file. I don't have yet tested on a **read** scenario, but here an exemple of how to **write** some Stream data to your own FileStream on a deeply nested path:

```
using (var fileHandle = ZlpIOHelper.CreateFileHandle(very_long_outputPath, ZetaLongPaths.Native.CreationDisposition.CreateAlways, ZetaLongPaths.Native.FileAccess.GenericAll, ZetaLongPaths.Native.FileShare.Read))
{
    using (FileStream streamWriter = new System.IO.FileStream(fileHandle, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
    {
       //Your code logic here
    }
}
```